# Magento Error website

Tags: system-config

***Getting The below error in website***

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in /home/bhuwalfashion/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 30
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell more information like magento version and platform.

Comment: Magento 1. and php

Answer (score 0):

Download magento source code and replace with this file

```
 lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Open this file and make it public instead of protected 

/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php
--------------------------------
```